# how to sum multi fields in flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am sum one fields in Apache Flink 1.10 like this,I am receive RabbitMQ messages and handle it in memory,finally save it to MySQL,the sum operate code like this:

```
 consumeRecord.keyBy("gameType")
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .sum("realPumpAmount")
                .addSink(new SinkFunction<ReportPump>() {
                    @Override
                    public void invoke(ReportPump value, Context context) throws Exception {
                        // handle sink logic
                    }
                });
```

Now I want to sum multi fields in the entity of MQ like this:

```
consumeRecord.keyBy("gameType")
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .sum("field1","field2")
                .addSink(new SinkFunction<ReportPump>() {
                    @Override
                    public void invoke(ReportPump value, Context context) throws Exception {
                        // handle sink logic
                    }
                });
```

Is there any way to implement this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` reducer accepts just a single field. You can write such reducer yourself:

```
consumeRecord.keyBy("gameType")
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
    .reduce((d1, d2) -> {
        d1.field1 += d2.field1;
        d1.field2 += d2.field2;
        return d1;
    })
    .addSink(new SinkFunction<ReportPump>() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(ReportPump value, Context context) throws Exception {
            // handle sink logic
        }
    });
```